# Is there a continuous nowhere Lanczos generalized differentiable function?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

The Lanczos generalized derivative comes from local regression, and is described in [this pdf](http://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/SeniorProjectArchive/2006/washbuea.pdf).

(You do not need to read that to understand my questions.)

If you do read it, observe that I'm pulling out the constant $\frac32$ since that doesn't affect my questions.

Does there exist a continuous function $\: f : \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R} \:$ such that for all real numbers $x$,

($\hspace{.01 in}$i) $\quad$ $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0}\;\left(\frac1{h^3} \cdot \left(\displaystyle\int_{-h}^h\:\left(t\cdot f(x+t)\right)\:dt\right)\right) \;\;$ does not exist?

($\hspace{.01 in}$ii) $\quad$ if $\;\; \displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0}\;\left(\frac1{h^3} \cdot \left(\displaystyle\int_{-h}^h\:\left(t\cdot f(x+t)\right)\:dt\right)\right) \;\;$ exists then it is infinite?

Whenever $f$ is symmetric about $x$, the limit equals zero (since the integral will be zero independent of $h\hspace{.01 in}$.) $\:$ This rules out all of the continuous nowhere differentiable functions that I am aware of.

Comment: Have you tried any of the standard continuous nowhere differentiable functions?  What happens?  Also, it might help if you gave some background or references on this notion of derivative.

Comment: Have you tried the [Baire category approach](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~marker/math414/fs.pdf)?

Comment: [This construction](http://www.apronus.com/math/nodiffable.htm) creates nonsymmetric zigzags: starting with $f(x)=x$, we get a piecewise linear function with slopes $9/4,-3/2,9/4$, etc. I think this might be an example of (i).